# Remapped LWin in windows 8.1 disables input when used to open any window

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a new user to AutoHotkey and I've been trying the following, which works just fine.

```
LCtrl::LWin ; left command to alt

LAlt::LCtrl ; left alt to command (windows key)

LWin::LAlt ; left win to left alt
```

However when I tried to use the winkey combination to open some window(e.g) <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, or <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, the corresponding window pops up but I cannot type anything in the input field.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @jww This question is about programming with AutoHotkey. It is not off-topic question.

Comment: @cpburnz This question is about programming with AutoHotkey. It is not off-topic question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH This question is about programming with AutoHotkey. It is not off-topic question.

Comment: @saimeunt This question is about programming with AutoHotkey. It is not off-topic question.

Comment: @La-comadreja This question is about programming with AutoHotkey. It is not off-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to launch script with admin privileges.
- Always use AutoHotkey and its documentation from
  http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official
  website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is
  outdated and you may have some problems using them!
- Also make sure that no other code is blocking input. Just launch
  script with only code you have provided and check if input is
  blocked.

Comment: Afaik the new website was created because the new admin of the old site didn't care about certain bugs on the site. So the new site isn't "official" afaik. Though it's certainly better.  
I would also suggest to simply use the help file which came with your version of autohotkey. This way the servers don't need to handle unnecessary traffic and you get way faster results.

Comment: @Forivin ahkscript.org is official website becose main developer of AutoHotkey Lexikos puts new versions only at ahkscript.org , so development is at ahkscript.org only and so it is new official website of AutoHotkey. I think official website is called website where software development is based. At that time AutoHotkey development is based at ahkscript.org . autohotkey.com distributes legacy autohotkey version which is 5 years old.

Comment: So opening a new website offering updated versions of an open source project makes it the official website? I don't think so.  Both sites link to the latest version btw.

Comment: Oh nvm the autohotkey.com download used to link to ahkscript.org, but it doesn't anymore...

Comment: @Forivin *AutoHotkey Foundation LLC* is on the ahkscript.org here: http://ahkscript.org/foundation/ certificate: http://ahkscript.org/certificate_of_organization.pdf I think that main developer and *AutoHotkey Foundation LLC* is enough reason to call ahkscript.org official website of AutoHotkey.

Comment: @KZNatt I don't know enough about what exactly a foundation is and who can create one. But from what I heared, Chris gave the whole rights of AutoHotkey to Polyethene and Polyethene has nothing to do with ahkscript.org. So that's pretty much all I can say to that.

Comment: @Forivin As far as I know Chris liked the idea of *AutoHotkey Foundation LLC* and supported its creation. Also he gave to manage autohotkey.com not of the AutoHotkey. After Chris stopped developing Autohotkey it was developing mainly by Steve Gray not by Polyethene.